# How to make separate Lips control the mouth (Cavity) animation?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, shape-keys

I've create the lips using bezier curve and assigned bezier circle in the bevel object. There's a simple body with a cavity, I want the cavity boundary to follow the animation of lips, because Lips are made of bezier curve they are easier to animate, makes sense?

Any other suggestions?

[image: The Lips and the body]

Comment: You could possibly use hooks to do this but you will need a large number of vertices to make sure all the vertexes around the mouth are attached to a hook on the lips. This might not always work though. Most models with lips just have the lips be part of the face as part of the same mesh.

Comment: Use [**hooks**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/hooks.html?highlight=hook) to drive the deformation. See: [How can I make two objects share the same vertex?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42958/how-can-i-make-two-objects-share-the-same-vertex/42970#42970)

Comment: @VampyreSix  ok so I tried using hooks, but hooks doesn't allow hooking a vertice from one mesh object to a vertice on other mesh object, it hooks one vertice to a new object (Plain arrows by default). I think I'll need to compromise.

Comment: @cegaton I wanted to hook one vertice directly to other, so I could use shape-keys, but I don't see how that will be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in this answer: [How can I make two objects share the same vertex?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42958/how-can-i-make-two-objects-share-the-same-vertex/42970#42970), you can use [**Hooks**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/hooks.html?highlight=hook) to drive the deformation.

- In Edit mode select a vertex on the mesh.
- Press the <kbd>Space Bar</kbd>, type "hook" and select "Hook to new object"

  This will create an empty that controls that specific vertex.
- Exit edit mode.
- Select the Newly created Empty, and while pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the curve to make it the active object.
- Enter edit mode and select a control point in the curve that matches the vertex you want to control.
- Press the <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> and type "vertex", select "**Make Vertex Parent**" (or Pres <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>P</kbd>)

  Now the control point in the curve moves the empty, and that in turn controls the vertex on the mesh.

[image]

- Repeat the process for the rest of the vertices in the mesh so that you can control them with the curve.

[image]

Comment: The only thing I can't do in this way would be using drivers, because I cant't use shape-keys on the hooks but this is the closest I'll get to what I'm aiming for.

Comment: You can use shape keys on the curve.

Comment: Yes I know shape keys can be used on the curves but after following the above process the curve will be controlled by the new object it has been hooked to, right? So to control both, the lips and the mouth I'll need to move the new object they have been hooked to, which doesn't support shape-keys.