# How to constrain vertices of an object to tracked point

Tags: constraints, tracking

I have a video where I'm moving my fingers around (4 points) and what I want to achieve is having an object whose vertices I want to move using my fingers.

I already set up the tracking of the points so is there a way to constrain vertices to these tracks?

Comment: Once you've tracked the points you need on the video, you can set them as empties, then you can use those empties as **hooks**. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61757/track-object-and-draw-path-on-top-of-video/61772#61772 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101882/how-to-make-separate-lips-control-the-mouth-cavity-animation/101926#101926