# 2 Objects but keep vertices joined?

Tags: objects

How can I split one object into two but keep the vertices joined where the object was split?

If I use two objects the animation creates a gap between the two since they don't influence each other.

I need two objects so I can swap meshes, for example clothes mesh.

Comment: Two different objects cannot have common vertices. The vertices of two objects can be in the same place but they cannot be connected. It seems to me that you need hooks, where a vertex can be controled by an empty and that empty can be controlled by a vertex on the other object. See: 
[How can I make two objects share the same vertex?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42958/how-can-i-make-two-objects-share-the-same-vertex/42970#42970)

Comment: You can also parent one to the vertex of the other but whether the transformations of one are going to affect the other is another matter.

Comment: As long a the weights are identical shouldn't the vertex positions stay identical as well provided you don't move the objects themselves?