# How to drive rest pose bone positions? (For procedural facial rigging)

Tags: modifiers, interface, bones, drivers

I am using bones to emulate facial muscles and I would like the head of each bone to automatically stay attached to an associated vertex, so that when I apply my topology for different characters the bone placement automatically updates with the relevant remolded vertex position.

I have tried setting Bone Constraints to perform a Damped Track targeting an Empty (with the intention of Hooking that Empty to the related vertex, as described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42958/how-can-i-make-two-objects-share-the-same-vertex)), but this constrains me from setting further poses, and it does not automatically update the rest pose / edit pose as Bone Constraints appear only to be available during Pose Mode.  I intially thought to simply add a Driver to the bone's head position, however the bone's position data (as visible in Edit Mode) notably does not expose the ability to attach a Driver to those coordinates - which is a shame.

I was hoping to accomplish this task within the standard UI, but perhaps this will require I learn scripting for Blender.  Looking forward to community ideas!

Comment: That's right, contraints are made for posing. Blender offers no way of procedurally setting up edit bones, short of using Python.